# Can a single eclipse C++ project link different libraries differently for different platforms?

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, cross-compiling

I have a C++ eclipse project that I would like to easily compile In Windows and OSX.

The project is currently using an automatically generated makefile.

The libraries that I need vary depending on the platform.

In osx I'm using the CoreMidi, CoreAudio, and CoreFoundation frameworks.
In Windows I'm using the winmm.lib and multithreaded libraries.

What's the simplest way to link different libraries/frameworks depending on the current platform?

I'm currently using the gcc toolchain on OSX. Should I start using the cross compile toolchain?

Should I have two projects. One for working in windows, and one for osx, checking them both in to version control?

Should I write a custom makefile instead of using the automatically generated option that has different g++ arguments depending on the platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Eclipse can run fine on both OS X and Windows, it is not designed to be used in this way.

The best way to do it is to use separate IDE projects for each platform. This this is the easiest way to have unique compilation settings for multiple platforms.

Yes, you can use two eclipse projects. Alternatively, it's not unusual to have a X-Code project for OSX, and a Visual Studio Project for MS Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I personally had the same goal for a project and came to the conclusion the [Qt framework](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) was the best thing for me. It handles multiple languages, unicode strings, XML, network communications, native looking user interfaces, console applications: it can do an AWFUL lot.

However, as Paul pointed out, you really have to plan it from the start.

Qt does a good job of abstracting the platform away (in a module called QtCore) allowing you to write vanilla C++ code, or you can chose to include some Qt C++ language extensions which a Qt helper application called the moc (meta object compiler) creates vanilla C++ from, which can then be compiled by most common C++ compilers.

It also has a nifty cross-platform makefile generator called qmake which works on project files to create normal make files for the platform its running on.

Off the top of my head at least Windows XP & 7, OSX 10.4, 10.5, 10.6 are supported currently.  But note that OSX Lion is (as of writing) not officially supported but I suspect it will be in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I am not sure you can easily make it cross-platform. Even without using third-party library, you have to provide separate code for osx and windows. Most of time, they design the system as cross-platform first. It's really hard to make an existing project on single-platform to cross-one. If you have the cross-platform requirement, you'd better design in that way first and rewrite from scratch.

Comment: I'm just beginning to work on the project now, so it's not too late to "rewrite from scratch" - Do I just need to abstract the platform dependent code to platform specific libraries? Maybe I should re-phrase the question to "How do I link different libraries on different platforms"